# NPGSqlDataAdapter fills irrelavant data

Tags: database, postgresql, npgsql

I am facing some weird issue about npgSqlDataAdapter. When i send "select name,salary from salary;" some times table gets filled with correct data and sometimes it gets Date. I am not getting how is it possible. Code is as follows:

```
        DataTable table = null;
        try
        {                

            table = new DataTable();
            using (NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(query,Connection))
            {
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Cannot get data from database: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return table;
```

Comment: Please simplify this into a self-contained example where "query" doesn't get supplied from outside, etc. Make sure it's not just a programming mistake where you're calling it with two different SQL queries, etc.